# Adding html class/ID to hook_menu generated link

Tags: php, css, class, hyperlink, drupal-7

I'm trying to add a class or ID to a link generated from my hook_menu code included below:

```
<?php

function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['mypage_redirect'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'mypage_redirect_callback',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access arguments' => array("access content"),
        'title' => 'My module generated page',
        'options' => array(
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'class' => array(
                                'test-class'
                            )
                        )
                    ),
    );
    return $items;
}
```

All I'm trying to accomplish a simple link with a class of 'test-class' so I can style it but the instructions I followed to get the above code has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
function commons_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['test'] = array(
    'title' => t("test"),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'options' => array(
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => 'test-menu'
      )
    )
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Have cheked other forums too!!.. the attibutes doesn't work with `MENU_LOCAL_ACTION` or `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` 
Your code looks fine.. did you try clearing cache after the changes?